# Find value of input and count up with delay using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to take the value which will be a number from an input field and then output that value counting from 0 to X (Value from input). I also need to have each write delayed by 20ms times the current input value (So for the value 4 it would be 4*20ms) using Jquery.

What do I need to add to this wh for that to happen please?
 //EDITED

```
   $( ".button" ).click(function() {
    var honeypotValue = $( "#numberBox" ).val(); 
    if ($("#numberBox").val() != ''){
    $( ".honeypot").html(honeypotValue + " Bees");
    var loops = 0;
    var loop = function(){
    while(loops < honeypotValue){
    loops++;
    console.log(loops);
    }
    };
    loop();
}
else {
alert("Honeypot Empty")
}
});
```

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Could you show me some example code so I can try to understand that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the **setInterval**  function to automatically print out the number of bees.  I used the i-- operator to decrement the number of bees.

```
<button class="button">test</button>
<input value="12" id="numberBox" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( ".button" ).click(function() {
        var honeypotValue = $( "#numberBox" ).val(); 
        if ($("#numberBox").val() != '') {
            var max = Number(honeypotValue), i = 0;
            tempFunction = function () {
                console.log(i);
                if (i < max) {
                    setTimeout(tempFunction,20*i);   
                }
                i++;
            }
            setTimeout(tempFunction,20*i);          
        }
        else {
            alert("Honeypot Empty")
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Im still struggling to get it to do what I need. How would I get this to count up and log to the console only?

Comment: I get I can use this, but im not sure how I add the interval

Comment: var loops = 0;
var loop = function(){
while(loops < honeypotValue){
loops++;
console.log(loops);
}
};
loop();

Comment: I fixed it, go ahead and test it now.  You can't use normal loops if you also want it to sleep as well.  That's why we are using the setInterval function to work around that issue.

Comment: Sorr one more thing, does this add the 20ms times the current input value each time? Im just trying to work out where that is in the code

Comment: Are you saying you want the delays to go as follows: 20, 40, 60, 80, 100... etc.? Or is it: 20, 20, 20, 20?

Comment: It takes the current value of i and * that by 20ms... so 1*20ms.. 2x20ms..3x20ms

Comment: Great that makes sense now